# Vertically fixed navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to create vertically a fixed navigation bar for my site. Currently i use the one that has been mentioned on various posts here:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'navbar.css' %}">   

    <script type="application/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var navPos = $('.nav_menu').offset().top; //Sticky navbar
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
                if (scrollPos >= navPos) {
                    $('.nav_menu').addClass('fixed');
                } else {
                    $('.nav_menu').removeClass('fixed');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    .....
    <div class="nav-container">
        <div class="nav_menu">
            Bars go here
    ....
```

And CSS:

```
.nav-container .nav_menu.fixed {position: fixed; z-index: 10000; top: 0; width: 195px; padding-left: 8px}
```

This solution works great, the navbar is sticked, in my case the navbar is on the top left side of the page. If i scroll down it perfectly follows the scroll. In case i open the gape using a small window and i stoll down plus right the bar follows (as it should happen). However i would like the bar to only follow vertically, in case someone scrolls left or right the bar should stay where it is.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: you would probably need to set the left position to minus the scroll() left on horizontal scroll - position fixed is relative to the viewport so when you horizontally scroll it stays fixed.  Or you could have an inner container in the nav_menu and size it to the width of the document on page load and resize

Comment: @Pete The first solution seems easier, however i dont have experience with JS. Can you please tell me how can i set the left ops to be -scroll()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop the horizontal fixed by applying minus left scroll:

```js
var $window = $(window);
var navPos = $('.nav_menu').offset().top; //Sticky navbar

$window.scroll(function() {
  var scrollPos = $window.scrollTop();
  var left = 0 - $window.scrollLeft();

  if (scrollPos >= navPos) {
    $('.nav_menu').addClass('fixed').css('left', left + 'px');
  } else {
    $('.nav_menu').removeClass('fixed').css('left', 0);
  }
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 2000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav_menu {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 195px;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><br><br>
<div class="nav_menu"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but using this the nav bar doe snot move. https://jsfiddle.net/pge5noss/10/

Comment: It's an example, apply what I have changed to your code - you asked how to move the bar left so all you need are the bits of js to do that from above

Comment: I am sorry i totally miss something. If i use your setup here https://jsfiddle.net/pge5noss/15/ it works perfectly. However if i make a file asd.js, asd.css and index.html, copy the very same code (and also add `<script type="text/javascript" src="asd.js"></script>`) and its not working. What am i missing?

Comment: are you running it on document ready?  I have removed that from my snippet because the snippet does that bit automatically

Comment: Running what? I just added statement `<script type="text/javascript" src="asd.js"></script>` which i think imports the js file?

Comment: The js inside that file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165657/discussion-between-gabor-erdos-and-pete).